# Custom text for file input

Tags: html

Is there a way to change the text on a a file input in html?

Comment: In google chrome, it says Choose File on the button and tehn no file selected next to it.  Can I customize these?

Comment: You could create a hack like placing an absolute div over the file field or assigning a file field action to a text input field.

Answer (score 2):

[This is the only possible solution i know of.](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

**Javascript**

**Flash**

through javascript + css hack, you can do this as @Sarfaraz said.
Another option is use flash. In that case you have more control.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. That would have been a security hole. If that was possible, then everyone would be able to do this:

```
<form name="upload" action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" value="c:/passwords.txt">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>document.upload.submit()</script>
```

True, you can mimic it with a plain input field as @sAc mentions, but it would still not point to the *actual* file.