# How to fix display issue of Firefox with input[type="file"] in CSS

Tags: html, css

Reading from articles, I found out that `input[type="file"]` have unique views across different browsers.

I'm looking for a quick fix for this issue using CSS(only if possible) because I need to adjust only the `width` of the element.

Here is the site (`http://210.48.94.218/~printabl/contact/`) I'm currently working with. If browse the page with firefox, the page view gives undesirable output.

[image]

**Q: How can I adjust the width using CSS? Or any easiest fix for this issue.**

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably style file inputs with CSS since they're rendered differently across each browser.

Maybe this hack is what you're looking for: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793014/jquery-trigger-file-input). I'm not sure how reliable it is across browsers though.

Answer (score 0):

The input attributes will size the fields

```
<input name="" type="text" size="10" maxlength="40" size=50>
```

CSS styling works as you'd expect

```
input[type=file] {width: 100%}
```

Possibly duplicate [How to style an input[type=file] in css that would render crossbrowser compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921471/how-to-style-an-inputtype-file-in-css-that-would-render-crossbrowser-compatibl?rq=1)

Comment: im sorry but im talking about input[type="file"] and NOT input[type="text"]